# How to compute weighted cosine similarity between two vectores in Python

Tags: python, scipy

Hi i'm trying to calculate the cosine similarity between two vectors. I'm using scipy to do so.

```
>>> from scipy import spatial
>>> 1 - spatial.distance.cosine([3, 45, 7, 2], [2, 54, 13, 15])
0.97228425171234989

>>> 1 - spatial.distance.cosine([3, 45, 7, 2], [6, 54, 13, 15])
0.97216484313108098
```

But if i bring minor change in first element i get almost same similarity. But my first element of vector is very important and minor change means a lot to me. So i was wondering how can i add weight for each index of vector to get weighted cosine similarity between two vectors. Thanks

Comment: Pass the weights in the 3rd argument, `w=`? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html

Comment: @IljaEverilä I tried to do so, although in documentation it says cosine() can take three arguments but when i add third argument it gives error TypeError: cosine() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given).

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @IljaEverilä My version was not updated one, i updated the version and is now working. Thank you so much

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: FYI: My answer here explains how weighting works: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/448904/216706